# How do I access multiple arrays of objects while creating a table in JS

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a table through javascript and I need to list in the table elements of two different object arrays called `array1` and `array2`.

I have tried using two `for` structures, one within the other and then list the 4 `items`, but the result is each item shown several times when each one should only be listed once. Hope you can help. Thank you.

```
var array1 = [{name:"name"},{lastname:"lastname"}];
var array2 = [{age:"age"},{date:"date"}];

function myFunction(){

var list = "<table width='800' border='1'>" ;
    list = list + "<tr>";
    list = list + "<td colspan='4'> LIST HEADER</td>";
    list = list + "</tr>";
    list = list + "<tr>";
    list = list + "<td> NAME </td>";
    list = list + "<td> LASTNAME </td>";
    list = list + "<td> AGE </td>";
    list = list + "<td> DATE </td>";
    list = list + "</tr>";


    for(var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++){
        for(var j = 0; j < array2.length; j++){
            list += "<tr>";
            list += "<td>" + array1[i].name + "</td>";
            list += "<td>" + array1[i].lastname + "</td>";
            list += "<td>" + array2[j].age + "</td>";
            list += "<td>" + array2[j].date + "</td>";
            list += "</tr>";
   }
}
    list += "</table>";
    $("#listall").html(list);
 }
```

Comment: You will need two `for` loops, but they should not be nested.

Comment: As @MikeMcCaughan said, but if `array1` has always the same length as `array2`, you just need 1 `for` lopp.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Would the items appear each under the correct LIST ITEM if I use two loops?

Comment: did both of arrays always have same length?

Comment: is there any reason why you don't simply have a single array?
     var array = ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"];

Comment: @FadhlyPermata No, each array has more keys with values that do not have the same length. This code is an example of my code and the issue I need to solve.

Comment: @derp This is an overly simplified version of my code. The actual arrays have many keys and values that do not have the same size and information. That is why I need to access both arrays.

Comment: It's a bit confusing as to what those list item headers mean exactly. You should probably post a more representative example of the data in the arrays, and explain how those data are to be displayed in the table.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Let's say I have an array with a key `Date` and another key `Name`, then another array with a key `Lastname` and another key `Age`. And I need to make a table of the data of both arrays together, a column for the date, another for name, another for lastname and date.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the appropriate example data and how you're expecting to know which object has which key. Currently, the code you have will show a blank in the third cell of the first row because `array[0].item3` does not exist. How would you know which key is in which element?

Comment: @hendrix If so, how you can mapping each of them? can you explain more detail. I think without the key it will confusing to mapping each of the data

Comment: What do you expect the table output to look like if the arrays have differing numbers of elements?  Please provide an example.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I have edited so you can understand what I want to do.

Comment: @FadhlyPermata I just edited.

Comment: @RJM I have edited.

Comment: So, what is the correspondence between the number of elements in each array, and how many rows are in the table? Currently you're showing two arrays, each with two elements, which should result in a table with a single row. How do you know when to add a new row?

Comment: I think, with your both array content, you only have one row data. so, why did you need to looping them? since each element has been placed into same row.

Comment: @FadhlyPermata I will create more arrays just like these to, that is why I need to loop in order to list all of the information and put it in a table.

Comment: if so, will be good idea if you show more then one rows (elements). so other peoples know what you mean & what you need. because you only said "array" not "nested array".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first check your original code by `console.log()` ,you may be figure out what is wrong.But I suggest my approach to your condition like below...

change from

```
for(var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < array2.length; j++){
        list += "<tr>";
        list += "<td>" + array1[i].name + "</td>";
        list += "<td>" + array1[i].lastname + "</td>";
        list += "<td>" + array2[j].age + "</td>";
        list += "<td>" + array2[j].date + "</td>";
        list += "</tr>";
```

}
}
to like this

```
 for(var i in array1){
        list += "<tr>";
            if(i == 0){
            list += "<td>" + array1[i].name+ "</td>";
            list += "<td>" + array2[i].lastname + "</td>";
            list += "<td>" + array1[parseInt(i)+1].age+ "</td>";
            list += "<td>" + array2[parseInt(i)+1].date + "</td>";  
            }
            else{
            list += "<td>" + array1[parseInt(i)-1].name+ "</td>";
            list += "<td>" + array2[parseInt(i)-1].lastname + "</td>";
            list += "<td>" + array1[i].age+ "</td>";
            list += "<td>" + array2[i].date + "</td>";      
            }                                    
            list += "</tr>";   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay i think this is what you want:

```
var combinedArray = array1.concat(array2);
var combinedObject = combinedArray.reduce(function(obj, propObj){
    return _.merge(obj, propObj)
}, {});
```

We have a whole bunch of property values in a lot of different arrays. We first combine all of this into one array and then reduce the combined array into a single object.

We then print out the keys that you want.

https://jsfiddle.net/50ndu5s6/1/